# SQL - add inside seq row numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, row-number

I have unions query and I am trying to add a separate seq numbers in each line type The query return :

[image: first table]

I want to add seq row numbers that will work like this :

[image: second table]

How can I had in sql or hanna DB this kind of row numbers?

Comment: Add your info as text/code not as images please

Comment: Show your current query.  How are the rows being ordered?

Comment: In the B (2) group you perhaps meant Ab (3) at the end...?

Comment: What is "hanna DB"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    MainType, 
    ' (', 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MainType ORDER BY MainType), 
    ')'
  ) as MainType,
  CONCAT(
    LineType, 
    ' (', 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MainType, LineType ORDER BY MainType, LineType), 
    ')'
  ) as LineType
FROM 
  table
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Hanna Db but If you are using SQL server you can try below and see if this is what you want

```
Create Table #Table 
(
    MainType varchar(4),
    LineType varchar(6)
)

Insert Into #Table
Values 
('A', 'Aa'),
('A', 'Ab'), 
('A', 'Aa'), 
('A', 'Ac'),
('A', 'Ab'),  
('B', 'Aa'), 
('B', 'Ab'), 
('B', 'Ab'), 
('B', 'Ac'),
('B', 'Ab'),
('C', 'Aa'),  
('C', 'Ac'),  
('C', 'Aa')


Select *, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order By MainType) as MainTypeRank,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By MainType, LineType Order By LineType) as LineTypeRank
 From #Table
 Order by MainType
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get your exact result

```
Create Table #TempTable 
(
    MainType varchar(4),
    LineType varchar(6)
)

Insert Into #TempTable
Values 
('A', 'Aa'),
('A', 'Ab'), 
('A', 'Aa'), 
('A', 'Ac'),
('A', 'Ab'),  
('B', 'Aa'), 
('B', 'Ab'), 
('B', 'Ab'), 
('B', 'Ac'),
('B', 'Ab'),    
('C', 'Aa'),  
('C', 'Ac'),  
('C', 'Aa')
```

Above is sample data . Script to get  the result

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Lag(maintyperank) 
                OVER( 
                  ORDER BY maintyperank) = maintyperank THEN '' 
         ELSE maintyperank 
       END AS MainType, 
       linetyperank 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               maintype + '(' 
               + Cast(Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY maintype) AS VARCHAR(5)) 
               + ')' AS MainTypeRank, 
               linetype + '(' 
               + Cast(Row_number() OVER (partition BY maintype, linetype ORDER 
               BY 
                      linetype)AS 
               VARCHAR(5)) 
               + ')' AS LineTypeRank 
        FROM   #TempTable)Dt
```

Result

```
       MainType            linetyperank
        -------------------------
        A(1)            Aa(1)
                        Aa(2)
                        Ab(1)
                        Ab(2)
                        Ac(1)
        B(2)            Aa(1)
                        Ab(1)
                        Ab(2)
                        Ab(3)
                        Ac(1)
        C(3)            Aa(1)
                        Aa(2)
                        Ac(1)
```